# Pushing subfolders of a repository in Git?

Tags: git, push

I have just started using Git, but I'm a little confused. I've just about gotten my head around pushing the whole local directory to GitHub using this command when in the working directory of my choice:

`git push -u origin master`

Now, my repository is called `/websites`. I will have numerous subfolders on my Mac, like `/websites/website1`, `/websites/website2`, etc.

What if I want to only push a specific subfolder in my main repository? Is that possible? Also how would I pull back from only a subfolder too?

Comment: Git works with commits and branches. You cannot push files or directories, but only commits. Of course commits have trees (folders) and blobs (files). In your situation you probably want to stop making `/websites` a git repo and instead make all those sites separate repositories.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how git works. The behavior you're describing is how something like `rsync` or `scp` works. Git works by commits as opposed to individual files or directories. That being said, when you push with git, it only pushes changed files, as opposed to everything.

A better workflow for you would be to make each individual website its own repository. If you don't want to deal with that, you may find that keeping each website in its own branch helpful.

Comment: Ah wait, as long as it pushes only **changes** then that's fine, it works out. For example, if I'm modifying website 2, I can commit changes to site 2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `git subtree` ([git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt))