# How to push code on github repository folder?

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

At first I have create a repo on GitHub. Then I have created a folder on that repo. Now my Question is that how to push code on that folder from my pc .

i have tryed this command to connect this folder from my pc  GitBash  by this command:

```
git remote add origin { github url of my repo}/tree/main/WEEK%202/module%20-%206.5.git
```

i have chacked this command :
 `git remote -v`

`origin  { github url of my repo}tree/main/WEEK%202/module%20-%206.5.git (fetch) origin { github url of my repo} /tree/main/WEEK%202/module%20-%206.5.git (push)`

when ever i give git push command it says :

````
git push origin main```
`fatal: repository '{ github url of my repo} tree/main/WEEK%202/module%20-%206.5.git/' not found`
````

Comment: `https://github.com/zubayer-talukder/Zubayer_Phitron_CPP_for_DSA` is the URL of your repo, remove the stuff trailing it.

Comment: BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44980222/7976758 You cannot push into subfolder. This is because Git doesn't pull/push files — it pulls/pushes chains of commits. You can only push a branch (a chain of commits and references to the commits) to a repository, not a file/directory to a subfolder. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+into+subfolder

Answer (score 0):

the error message of git push command Showing that URL of your repository is not correct . **make sure you copy correct url and then try it again .**
If still facing and issue let me  know with more information

and "git remote add origin "

to add url in this command refer screenshot[image]

Comment: if i do what you are saying this will commit on the main branch repo . But i don't need that i want to push code on a folder or subfolder of a repo.